# Android Studio method Never Used

Tags: java, android-studio

I would like to know why in Android Studio my calculator app crashes because it could not find my method.

Here is my **MainActivity.java**:

```
public void OnClick(View v) {
  Button button = (Button) v;
  String str = button.getText().toString();

  EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
  edit.setText(total);
}
```

Here is the preview of my calc, all number buttons are set `onClick` to go to the `OnClick method` in my MainActivity. As you can see to the right of the picture below:

[image: activity_main.xml]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Put this in ``onCreate`` method

Comment: Post your code here, do not link to it.

Comment: my code is posted here

Comment: @jordan I think he means your ``MainActivity.java``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            edit.setText(total);
        }
    });

}
```